# Spring Boot load beans from a different module before

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I have two maven modules:

```
api-module
commons-module
```

The *api-module* contains the package *com.example.api* and the commons-module contains the package *com.example.commons*.

When I run the main app *com.example.api.ApiMain*, the execution fails.
It is because I have Mongo Repository classes defined in the *commons* package. The API controllers depends on them and since they are not instantiated before the *api* beans, the execution fails.

Here is the main api app:

```
package com.example.api;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"com.example.commons", "com.example.api"})
public class ApiMain {
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApiMain.class, args);
    }
}
```

How do I make sure that *com.example.commons* components are scanned before the beans in *com.example.api* are loaded?

I can use *@DependsOn* annoation on every bean in *com.example.api* but there are several classes and several more will be added in future and it will make the code ugly.

This problem can be solved if there is a way to instruct spring to load components from the *commons-module* first.

You may instruct me on how to perform this.

Comment: The problem isn't the ordering, the problem is not adhering to the best practices of Spring Boot. Your `ApiMain` should be in the `com.example` package and not the `com.example.api` package. If you put it in the toplevel package it will detect all classes and features on the full classpath. By not doing it you have to basically add `@EnableMongoRepositories` as well and for the packages you want. Which basically ties your `com.example.api` package to the `com.example.comons` package which you want to prevent I assume.

Comment: I have other SpringApplication module like com.example.other which has a main class. This kind of separation provides convenience and maintainability.

Comment: Does it... I doubt it, because now every module needs to know, explicitly, about the other modules it uses instead of being able to automatically detect features. Which defeats part of the purpose of Spring Boot of auto configuration because you now need to configure (parts) of your application yourself.

Comment: The application is big. The api module is totally different from the other module. The only thing in common between them is the repository module located the commons module. This way the jar size is also reduced.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever package is scanned first should not matter, as Spring will build a dependency graph and figure out the order in which beans are instantiated. If you want certain beans to be instantiated before others, as in lets say `BeanA` depends on `BeanB`, then `BeanA` will have a constructor `@Autowired BeanA(BeanB b)`.

Figuring out the order of instantiating is a fundamental aspect of Spring Dependency Injection, I would suggest you read up a bit more on Spring DI because I don't think you are grasping the concept of inversion of control and what Spring DI does.

But what it sounds like to me is you have something like:

```
public class BeanA {
    @Autowired
    BeanB b;
    public BeanA() {
        b.doSomething();
    }
}
```

But `b` is still null when `BeanA`'s constructor is called. Because you are performing some sort of instantiation in `BeanA` with `BeanB` you get a `NullPointerException`, instead you have to have: `BeanA(BeanB b)`.

Comment: Forgive me if I misunderstood this, but I think the user looks to check if the beans of other modules are being avaiable readily to use in this current module. I understand that it is still DI but could you brief on how to make sure that beans of another module is readily available?

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to think of beans as being in `modules`. Modules would be how you structure your code itself, it doesn't have anything to do with spring. As long as a bean is created any other bean can autowire it into itself. But if you for instance `BeanA` call `BeanB. doSomething()` in it's constructor, `b` will be null because it will not yet be injected, you need to have `@Autowired public BeanA(BeanB b)  `

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. I used below code for Rest API controller

```
@RestController
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@EnableResourceServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootWebApplication extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    //Dependancy injection using autowire
    @Autowired
    OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootWebApplication.class, args);
    }
```

Using this code for the normal controller which is rendering my HTML page

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Controller
public class WelcomeController {
```

Try this and let me know if this works or you still have some issue.

Comment: Yes. It worked. I added @EnableMongoRepositories and the application works now. Thanks.